# Solving matrix AX=B matrix for X

Tags: matrices

I'm having the following matrices in the form  A X= B.Where A & B matrix are known values. How can i solve for the matrix X?. Please provide me some formulas or Ideas for solving this.

Note: we need to use the least square method to get the best solution for X $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}A1&B1&C1\\A2&B2&C2\\...\\A10&B10&C10\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x1&x2&x3\\y1&y2&y3\\z1&z2&z3\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}A11&B11&C11\\A22&B22&C22\\...\\A1010&B1010&C1010\end{array}\right]$$

Can i use this formula for solving this?

$X= A^{-1}B$

Comment: $A$ isn't square, so $X = A^\dagger B = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T B$. But as a general thing you can convert $X$ to a vector unknown with slightly altered matrix $A$ and vectorized $B$ and then apply standard LS on $\tilde A\tilde x = \tilde b$

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? Assume i'm having very less knowledge in this math involved! Please convert this to an answer so that i can mark it as an answer!

Comment: I did so now. Is everything understandable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options here:

1. Solve $A\pmatrix{x_1\\y_1\\z_1} = \pmatrix{A_{1,1}\\\vdots\\A_{10,10}}$ et cetera as three LS-problems each with vector unknows
2. Convert $AX=B$ to a vector unknown system
   $$\pmatrix{A&0&0\\0&A&0\\0&0&A} \pmatrix{x_1\\y_1\\z_1\\x_2\\y_2\\z_2\\x_3\\y_3\\z_3} = \pmatrix{A_{1,1}\\\vdots\\A_{10,10}\\B_{1,1}\\\vdots\\B_{10,10}\\C_{1,1}\\\vdots\\C_{10,10}}$$
3. Use the same formula for the solutions of (1.) to solve the three in parallel
   $$X = A^\dagger B = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T B$$

Comment: Hi @AlexR! Can you please tell me what is A in Step 2? (A 0 0,0 A 0, 0 0 A)?

Comment: As in all other parts of the answer, the original LHS matrix (from $AX=B$)

Comment: My original Mat is 10x3. So in step two [30x9][9x1]. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The new matrix is $I_3 \otimes A$ with the kronecker product, its size is $3\cdot 10 \times 3\cdot 3 = 30 \times 9$.